# How to retrieve item with brackets in the name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to to get the value of an input element selected by its name.

When the element do not have `[]` in the name I can use:

```
var truc=$('input[name=one_name]').val();
```

But how do I do when I have `[]` in the name?

My code:

```
<input name="metre1_result[]" id="result1" value="0" class="nbr_result input">
<input name="metre1_result[]" id="result2" value="0" class="nbr_result input">

<input name="metre2_result[]" id="result1" value="0" class="nbr_result input">
<input name="metre2_result[]" id="result3" value="0" class="nbr_result input">
<input name="metre2_result[]" id="result7" value="0" class="nbr_result input">
```

```
//find value in loop for.
var titre_cal = $('input[name=metre' + i + '_result]').val();
// = undefined because []
```

Comment: Btw, your html has a duplicate id.  That's invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[name=metre2_result\\[\\]]')
```

or

```
 $('[name="metre2_result[]"]')
```

The inner brackets must be escaped or the value surrounded by double quotes.  Double quoting values is preferred, I believe.

Comment: FYI the escape character in jQuery is \\ so your first example isn't quite right.

Comment: Ah, lol, one of the cases where you have to escape it before it can escape the other character?  lol

Comment: YEs great, thank you lot of ;)